# How can I set a short local variable in a function to public

Tags: c#, wpf, variables, local, short

I'm building a wpf application in visual studios 2015, I'm brand new to visual studios and C# and have run into a small problem.

I have a function (shown below). On SelectionChanged event, I get the value of ClientList and set it to the local variable client.

```
 public void ClientList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        short client = (short)ClientList.SelectedValue;

        foreach (var orgComm in orgComms)
        {
            if(orgComm.OrgId == client)
            {
               CommList.ItemsSource = orgComm.CommunicationTemplateConfigs;
               CommList.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

I need this short local variable to be publicly available to other functions in the application although it sounds rather simple the answer seems to constantly evade me.

Comment: create a public property outside the method

Comment: Why is this question tagged with wpf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public short client;

public void ClientList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    client = (short)ClientList.SelectedValue;

    foreach (var orgComm in orgComms)
    {
        if(orgComm.OrgId == client)
        {
           CommList.ItemsSource = orgComm.CommunicationTemplateConfigs;
           CommList.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

client variable is available through out the class.

Comment: Hi Ravi. I've noticed one of your suggested edits here: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17899412 - Everything looks good - but please don't add "thanks" to posts. In fact, if you see it included in a post, you should be removing it. Otherwise, the edit looks good; keep it up